# How to check if an element is a clickable button and not a text?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test a web application. there is an element that sometimes it's just a text and sometimes it's clickable.
How can I distinguish between when it's a clickable button and a simple text?
(the text inside of the element is the same in both situations.)
the only difference is **::after** pseudo-elements.

```
<h2 class="line_10001">
Goal
</h2>

<h2 class="line-10001">
Goal
::after
</h2>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Post the buttons html for both cases. The text  might be the same but there will be a difference somewhere, probably in the button html.

Comment: Are you the programmer of the web application that you are testing with selenium (have you got the source code, could you change it)?

Comment: actually no. I don't have access to change the code.

Comment: Both are clickable... but clicking just text many times won't trigger anything. We'll need more info and more of the surrounding HTML. A link to the page would help a LOT more.

Comment: To test a element is clickable or not, you should know, what happens after the click. first click the element, then check the changes are reflecting after the click. In selenium, basically all elements are clickable. only difference if you click on text. you will not find any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with help of javascript:

```
String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('h2.line_10001'),':after').getPropertyValue('content')";

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
```

now if you check the `content`, if there's no `:after` in element, the `content` will be "none".

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector and nth-child. For example for the first element will be:

```
h2:nth-child(1)
```

and for the second

```
h2:nth-child(2)
```

You can test the select in the browser console to see how if it works.

```
 $("h2:nth-child(1)");
 $("h2:nth-child(2)");
```

Get them both and check using WaitDriver which one is clickable and click on it.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. they are same elements in different resolutions.